# Is there a way to check the camera HAL version from a Java application?

Tags: android, android-camera, hal

Is there a way to check the camera HAL version from a Java application?

This is to verify that the camera2 api and HAL3 api is supported. Slide 38 http://www.slideshare.net/lbk003/an-devcon2013-camera3kaurfinal

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to know the exact HAL version of the device, and instead query the camera's capabilities through the camera API.

For the new camera2 API, look at the CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL and REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES fields to check whether the device has full-capability support or some lesser set of features.